# How can I have multiple objects follow a single path but maintain their original offset?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, constraints

Ultimately I'm trying to make something along the lines of:
That titbit. In an IDEAL dream scenario, I would like this with VWSC letters: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgiBkydMW8k

[image: original position of all objects]
I am trying to build up an animation where *all* of these letters fly in. There are a tremendous number of objects here. Trying to make a unique curve for each object to fly in and then set up all of the individual path constraints etc., seems like it would be a challenge. There has to be a better way.

Unfortunately, when I try to make the W follow the path of the bezier curve where the V already is, it all goes out the window.

[image: w off the screen]

You can see here that the W has been moved off into lala land. I cannot even get it remotely close to its original location. The cursor is at the original location, and attempting to move the W object to the cursor doesn't really do anything to improve the situation.

- Selection to cursor moves the W off into another lala place
- Selection to cursor (keep offset) doesn't improve things

I tried redoing the logo and not having all the objects share a parent axis, made a new bezier curve, set the end point of the bezier to share the origin with the "V," added a path constraint, and now the V is doing the same thing -- way off in lala land. "Selection to cursor" just sends the V off to some other crazy location, nowhere near the actual cursor.

I am really struggling here.

- Why do my objects keep ending up off in space when attached to a path and told to follow it?
- How do I get the objects back to their original positions, regardless of where the path is?

** EDIT
After calming down a bit  I used "Alt-G" to reset the object position, and now I have both the V and the W along the path:
[image]

However, what I really want is for the W to end up at its original location. Once it's attached to the path, trying to use G-X to move it at all even a tiny bit moves it A LOT. The "location" values also no longer really make sense.

When I get the W to the end of the path and then try to use "selection to cursor" to move it to where the cursor currently is, it zooms off to lala land. Selection to cursor (keep offset) does no better.

Comment: Hello please share your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably fare better by using several curves, then your objects would transition from A to B differently from one another and it would look more like your reference.

Regardless of whether you use a single curve or several, you should be aware that :

1.the curve object has to be untransformed, otherwise these (the transforms) will add up to the final transformation of the constrained objects.

2.the constrained objects' transforms will *also* add up to the constraint effect, so their relative positions before creating the whole setup matter. More specifically in your case, they should be placed in relation to the path's endpoint.

Here is an example using a single curve for several objects :
[image]

Note that I didn't use the constraint's "follow curve" option, because it makes the final placement of the constrained object dependent on the curve tilt, and it can be a pain to line up so that the object is oriented exactly like you want. If you still want to use it, you can work around that by easing in a *Copy Rotation* constraint on the object in the final frames of its travel.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the blend file! I hadn't thought about the transformation on the curve object. When instantiating the Bezier, I was scaling it and not moving its vertices. That probably has a tremendous amount to do with it.

Do you have any thoughts on how to do this with multiple curves easily? Someone suggested geometry nodes. Individual curves is a TREMENDOUS number of curves (well over 30). Granted I can duplicate them and then reposition them, but, still, some kind of mathy way would likely be better.

Comment: Yes, usually don't transform objects unless you know what you're doing, prefer transforming the data (points, vertices...).
If you turn your individual letters to instances you can animate them along a procedurally generated spline (which can be any shape). But that is a completely different way to go about the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "turn the individual letters to instances." Each letter right now is an individual object that came in from an imported SVG. When importing SVG you get really tiny things, so I did end up scaling those before applying extrusions to make the characters 3D.

Do you happen to have a YouTube or blog-type link to the technique you're describing (procedural generated spline animation)? Are you suggesting procedurally generating many splines (curves) for the letters to follow?

Comment: If creating and animating 30 objects along as many curves seems like too much work, then yes, generating curves procedurally can be simpler. If you need to change something over all the objects, it can be done quickly instead of having to replicate the change on every object. This is the main advantage of the procedural approach.

Here is a file to get you started : https://blend-exchange.com/b/M7E36X4v

I've highlighted some of the nodes that are pivotal to this working (in orange/yellow).

Comment: How did you add the lone "dots" in the geometry node editor so that you could more cleanly route the node connection lines? I can't figure out a search term that produces a good result.

Comment: These are reroutes, you can add them with shift+click+drag over connections

Comment: Thank you so much!