# How can I add noise/randomness to an object position after sampling a curve with geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm working towards making an intro video similar to the old FIA F1 intro:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgiBkydMW8k

I had some questions about path following previously:
[How can I have multiple objects follow a single path but maintain their original offset?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302449/how-can-i-have-multiple-objects-follow-a-single-path-but-maintain-their-original)

I've got a good set of nodes now for creating a "noisy" curve and causing the object to follow that path (original file):

[image]

I'm struggling now with adding "random noise" to that path follow. In other words, as the object follows the path, I want to randomly insert noise into the position/translation or rotation or scale. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. If I manage to get anything to "add," it usually ends up deforming the object and not actually *moving* the object.

- adding an additional "transform geometry" works, but whenever I try to plug something into it, the line turns red:
  [image: invalid vector addition?]
- using set position with the offset and a noise texture results in the object being deformed:
  [image: deformed object]

I'm not really sure how I can add some randomized translation/rotation/scale to this object after the path follow is implemented. Can someone help?

Updated file:

[image]

Updated nodes:
[image: added object sampling]

Answer (score 1):

### Add *Noise Texture* to the *Position*

You're using a *Sample Curve* node to get the position along the path. If you add noise to this position you should get the jitter you're looking for.

[image]

### A General Case

For a more general case in which the object is being translated in world space rather than along a curve, use a *Set Position* Node:

[image: cube moving on y axis with noise]

The *Set Postion* node will set the position of each vertex in the geometry base on the inputs.

We want to offset the position of each vertex based on the object's location in the world. Use the *Object Info* node to obtain the object's *Location*. run that through a *Noise Texture* node to get some randomness to the movement. Plug the resulting vector into the *Offset* input of the *Set Position* node.

Now the cube will appear to wiggle randomly as it moves through world space.

Comment: Is this an additional geometry node setup that you've attached, or is this the only thing attached to the cube?

When I tried to use "set position" with my blenderfile (shared in the OP), manipulating the offset did not move the object (no input to set position other than me manipulating values directly)

Comment: Actually, set position will offset the object from the curve, but if you look at the edit/picture I just made, adding noise to the offset results in deformation of the object and not actually movement off the path.

Comment: OK, I've updated my blend file above and when I move the object in space (eg: g+x) it does jiggle around. However, as I manipulate the "factor" setting for the curve sample (which is how it's following the path), it doesn't jiggle around. Whatever the singular value of the _original_ position of the object was is offset by some noise, but it doesn't update as it follows the path.

Comment: @ErikJacobs I updated the answer for your specific case where the desired object position is coming from the *Sample Curve* node. You can add in the noise right there

Comment: This is working almost perfectly, but in my particular case, it is now losing the "anchor to start" aspect. The noisyness needs to stop at the original position. The YT video has the noisy letters flying in and ending up in their final resting position, which is what I'm trying to achieve here. I tried plugging the output of the anchor to start block (map range) into various places before the transform geometry from your modification but was unsuccessful.

Q: How would I limit the injected noise to zero at the "start" of the curve?

Comment: Multiply the noise vector by the fac value of the curve. if the noise is multiplied by 0 (which is the value at the start), there will be no jitter there. I can add to the answer in a bit but I’m afk currently

Comment: I'm not sure where to pull the fac value. The "factor" output of the Sample Curve node appears to always be zero regardless of the factor _setting_ of that node. I'd be thrilled if you could add it but a little more direction might enable me to figure it out on my own.

Comment: Well, I tried an experiment, and it seemed to work. Let me know if that's what you were thinking. I used a "value" node and then piped its input into the "factor" setting of "sample curve." I also piped the "value" output into a new multiply node that sits between the existing multiply and add nodes. This effectively multiplies the noise vector by the value (which would be 0 at the start of the curve and 1 at the end of the curve). When I slide the value node's value around, the object "finishes" at the curve origin and is noisily displaced as it moves!

Comment: Excellent! yes I was thinking along those lines! nice work